# List.js Search Column and Return Values Greater Than

Tags: javascript, php, html, search, listjs

I am using [list.js](http://listjs.com/) to search/sort an unordered list which works well. However, I would like to add searching for a few columns that contain numeric values. When searched, it would return all the items equal to or greater than the searched value.

*Example*
**Values:** 24,65,95,104
**Search:** 80
**Returns:** 95,104

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance. 
I also found [this code](https://codepen.io/javve/pen/wKGKWL) which might be helpful:

```
$('.filter-2').on('click', function() {
  userList.filter(function(item) {
    var born = parseInt(item.values().born);
    console.log(born);
    if (born < 1986) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In plain javascript:

```
var  array = [24,65,95,104];
console.log(arr.filter(function (num){
    return number > 80;
}));
```

In list.js it's very similar with [filter method](http://listjs.com/api/#filter):

> ```
> itemsInList = [
>     { id: 1, name: "Jonny" }
>   , { id: 2, name: "Gustaf" }
>   , { id: 3, name: "Jonas" }
> ];
>
> listObj.filter(function(item) {
>     return item.values().id > 1;
> }); // Only items with id > 1 are shown in list
> ```